# Spam emails from my domain

Tags: email, spam, spam-blocker, spf

Do spam spoof emails pretending to be sent from your domain which [SoftFail](http://www.openspf.org/RFC_4408#op-result-softfail) SPF verification hurt your domain's reputation with spam filters?